# ImportError: Can't determine version for xlrd (trying to read excel)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I have imported `xlrd` for excel files to be read but I am getting the error

```
ImportError: Can't determine version for xlrd
```

Script below:

```py
import pandas as pd                                                                     
import os                                                                              
import numpy as np                                                                    
import xlrd                                                             
path=r"C:\Users\Vicky\Desktop\Python"                                                  
os.chdir(path)                
fcs=pd.read_excel('risk.xlsx')
```

Not sure why...

Comment: Have you tried to use `pip` to uinstall and then install the latest version of `xlrd`?  Or`pip install xlrd --upgrade`

Comment: Hi, what do you import `xlrd` for?

Answer (score 2):

i also had this problem, u can solve it in this way:

at first,

> pip uninstall xlrd

then,

> pip install xlrd==1.1.0